# Can if statements trigger a null exception?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

In my code i have a line that is generating a null pointer exception

```
 if (x[i].getPos() == "QB") {
     playerTextBox.setText(playerTextBox.getText() + "\n" + f.printPlayer(x, i));
 }
```

Im almost positive the null is not the array x. I debuged and there were objects that populated the array. I'm just curious now i guess for future purposes if x was null would you get a null pointer exception with
 `(x[i].getPos() == "QB")`?

Answer (score 5):

Well, `x[i]` is `null`, otherwise there won't be any exception. Also, you should compare `String`s using `equals`, not `==`.

Your `if` should look like this:

```
if (x[i] != null && "QB".equals(x[i].getPos()) {
    //...
}
```

By the way, I would recommend you using a `List<Yourclass>` rather than an array. Take into account than an array is filled with `null` values by default.

Comment: why is x[i] null, when i debug it tells me the array is populated with objects

Comment: @JGerulskis do something simple: add `if (x[i] == null) { System.out.println("x[" + i + "] is null!"); }`. That would help more than the debugger.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

```
if (x[i].getPos() == "QB")
```

will generate a null-pointer exception if `x[i]` is null. You can't invoke methods on `null`. Also, you're testing `String` reference equality (not value equality).

```
if (x[i] != null && x[i].getPos() != null && x[i].getPos().equals("QB"))
```

Comment: @JGerulskis if you will do comparison against a literal `String` (like "QB"), it's better to do the comparison the other way around: `"QB".equals(x[i].getPos())`, this implementation won't have `NullPointerException` even if `x[i].getPos()` returns `null`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is Yes.
If x is null then the position of x will cause an exception if you try to get it.
 So `x[i].getPos()` can cause a Null Pointer Exception.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they can.

`x[i].getPos()` will throw nullpointerexception if x[i] is null.

Any time you dot off something you should check for null if you are not confident it can't be null.  Short circuit evaluation is a popular way to achieve that.

`if (x[i] != null && x[i].getPos() == "QB") playerTextBox.setText(playerTextBox.getText() + "\n" + f.printPlayer(x, i));`

That would quietly pass this code by if `x[i]` was null.  However, you say you're confident it wasn't `x[i]` that was null.  Because you've placed the body of the if on the same line as it's condition the line number of the exception won't give you any hints about which dot caused the nullpointerexception.

if `playerTextBox` or `f` were null they will also produce nullpointerexceptions.  You'll have to decide if you want this code to fail quietly when they are null, throw an exception to be handled elsewhere, or somehow ensure they can't be left null.

If I assume you'd like it to throw `invalidargumentexception` when they are null I'd rewrite that code like this:

```
    if (playerTextBox == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("playerTextBox was null");
    }
    if (f == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("f was null");
    }
    if (x == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("x was null");
    }

    if (  x[i] != null && "QB".equals( x[i].getPos() )  ) {
        playerTextBox.setText(playerTextBox.getText() + "\n" + f.printPlayer(x, i));
    }
```

If you're confident that any of those can't be null you can remove the test for null.  IllegalArgumentException is appropriate for a context where the variable was passed in so it's state needs to be validated.  If you don't plan to fix that here in this method but you don't want to quietly do nothing the right thing to do is to throw an exception that something above you in the call stack will have to decide how to recover from.  If you have one way you plan to recover from IllegalArgumentExceptions it's very nice to be able to send all of these exceptions to one place to be resolved.